# How to use GTK_TREE? Error

Tags: tree, gtk

I'm trying to make a simple file browser using gtk+. I'm using Code::Blocks on Ubuntu 12.04.

My question is how exactly do I use GTK_TREE?

Every time I do say :

```
int make_tree (char *dir, GtkWidget *tree, GtkWidget *list)
  {
    ...
    gtk_tree_append(GTK_TREE(tree), treeitem);
    ...
  }
```

I get an error saying : undefined refference to  GTK_TREE.
When I start typing, codeblocks finds GTK_TREE.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GtkTree has been deprecated for a long time, and it's been broken for even longer. If the documentation you're looking at does not mention this, you should probably find new documentation...

You may want to use a TreeView and a model (such as a ListStore), see the [overview](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/TreeWidget.html).

I guess for completeness I should mention that in GTK+ < 3.0 you possibly can use GtkTree by defining GTK_ENABLE_BROKEN in your code. Doing that would be a really bad idea... so please forget I mentioned it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I will try to find a workaround then.